# Why does my page keep loading after the file is downloaded in php?

Tags: php, readfile, download

I have a php page that runs a bash script then downloads the output tar.  The issue is that once the file is downloaded the page just keeps loading and never redirects.  I have found some issues like this but nothing that seems applicable to my case.  My code is as follows:

```
<?php


    $output=shell_exec('cd /opt/dir/  && sudo ./collect_diagnostics.sh && cd -');
    $rows_output = explode("Report is in ", $output);
    $rows_output2 = explode(" ", $rows_output[1]);

    $path_parts = pathinfo($rows_output2[0]);
    $file_name  = $path_parts['basename'];
    $file_path  = "/opt/dir/test/".$file_name;

    if (is_readable($file_path )) { 
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');
        ob_clean();
        readfile($file_path);
    } else {
       echo "404 Error";
    }

    header( 'Location:./aps_control.php' ) ;
?>
```

Just to be clear I have the bash script working and the download does occur and has a valid file.  The only issues seem to be that the page never finishes loading and I am not sure if this is related but the file when unpacked in 7-zip says "There are some data after the end of the payload data : version_Placeholder.tar". Also I really want to know what I am doing wrong for personal improvement.

My main resource for learning how to download files was http://www.media-division.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/

Comment: To whoever down voted this please tell me why so I can avoid down votes in the future.  Otherwise it dose nothing accept potentially damage my ability to learn and ask questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to show a page and serve the file in the same request. Just serve the file.

If you would like the user to go to a new page with a back button, you should redirect them to that page, and that page should trigger a new page that does the download. Don't combine them.

Comment: ok did that I added a header( 'Location:./dir_control.php' ) ; and removed the button.  Still seeing the issue though.

Comment: @mando222 no, don't do that. *The file cannot do anything else than downloading the file*. No redirects, no output. After readfile is done, it's done.

Comment: Ok I went and divided this into two pages one that handles the script portion and provides the download link and one that does the download.  The only time the user will see the download page is if an error happens.  This seems to work even though it is not my original vision.  Thanks for the help.